# Upload Excel entries to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I have an excel file that several worksheet. One of the worksheet is called "Exceptions". This worksheet consists of five columns and multiples users log in their notes in this five columns. I'm trying to create a process where, whenever the user enters the information and click the button, it should upload to MS sql from that particular row without deleting or clearing out previous data. Also I'm interested in knowing the upload datetime and the upload user.

I have below vba code, that uploads the whole worksheet.But I'm looking something like to upload only the rows that user has last edited.

```vb
        Sub Upload_To_SQL()

        On Error GoTo err_handler

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        UPLOAD_TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now

        conn.ConnectionString = OpenFile("ABC.txt")
        conn.Open


                    Dim MasterPolicyNumber As String
                    Dim Author As String
                    Dim ExceptionsDate As Date
                    Dim ExceptionNotes As String
                    Dim iRowNo As Integer

                    'MS NEW ADDITIONS
                    Dim UPLOAD_USER As String

                        With Sheets("Exceptions")


                            'Skip the header row
                            iRowNo = 2


                            'Loop until empty cell in Submission No.
                            Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""

                                MasterPolicyNumber = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
                                Author = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
                                ExceptionsDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
                                ExceptionNotes = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
                                UploadDate = UPLOAD_TIMESTAMP
                                'MS NEW ADDITIONS
                                UPLOAD_USER = UserName


                    conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Property (" _
                    & " MasterPolicyNumber, Author, ExceptionsDate,ExceptionNotes, UploadDate)" _
                    & " values ('" & MasterPolicyNumber & "', '" & Author & "', '" & ExceptionsDate & "', '" & ExceptionNotes & "','" & UploadDate & "', '" & UPLOAD_USER & "')"

                            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
                            Loop

                        End With

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing


        MsgBox "All Data Imported to SQL Database.", vbOKOnly, "Notice"

        Worksheets("Exceptions").Activate

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        Exit Sub


  err_handler:
            MsgBox Error
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True


        End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know  if that's really possible.. but one options is to load the whole thing into a staging table.. then compare the values in the property table to the staging table.. and update as necessary.. use stored procedures to do this..

Comment: This looks like a job for... SQL Server Integration Services...

Comment: Yes. too easy and simple in *SSIS*

Comment: Can I do truncate table in vba and then execute the insert statement ?

Comment: You could ask the user to select the row(s) to be uploaded before they run the upload macro.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
'TRUSTED CONNECTION
    On Error GoTo errH

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer
    Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String
    Dim server, username, password, table, database As String


    With Sheets("Sheet1")

            server = .TextBox1.Text
            table = .TextBox4.Text
            database = .TextBox5.Text


            If con.State <> 1 Then

                con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
                'con.Open

            End If
            'this is the TRUSTED connection string

            Set rs.ActiveConnection = con

            'delete all records first if checkbox checked
            If .CheckBox1 Then
                con.Execute "delete from dbo.test"
            End If

            'set first row with records to import
            'you could also just loop thru a range if you want.
            intImportRow = 10

            Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
                strFirstName = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
                strLastName = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)
                Uploader = Environ("USERNAME")
                DateTimeStamp = Now()

                'insert row into database
                con.Execute "insert into dbo.test (FName, LName, Uploader, DateTimeStamp) values ('" & strFirstName & "', '" & strLastName & "', '" & Uploader & "', '" & DateTimeStamp & "')"

                intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
            Loop

            MsgBox "Done importing", vbInformation

            con.Close
            Set con = Nothing

    End With

Exit Sub

errH:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]